# How to add a github java dependency in sbt config?

Tags: scala, github, sbt

I've added this code to my Build.scala.

```
  lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")) dependsOn(jbcrypt)
  lazy val jbcrypt = RootProject(uri("https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt.git"))
```

But sbt fails with the error:

```
[error] (root/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: default#jbcrypt_2.11;0.1-SNAPSHOT: not found
```

How to tell sbt that it is Java not Scala?

How to reference to a specific branch or tag?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to resolve this from maven central?

Comment: @m-z mvnrepository has only the old version of the lib "0.3m". I'd like to use a fresh version from the master branch.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible if the project you're trying to depend on doesn't have an SBT build (although stuff's being added to SBT all the time that surprises me, so who knows).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building a project from source is only possible if the referenced project is a sbt project. sbt doesn't know of all the different build systems out there, so how is it supposed to know how to build a non sbt project?

It is possible to add support for other build systems through a sbt plugin but this may be a lot of work.

Your referenced project is a simple Maven project, which means that you can easily create a sbt project from it. Just fork the repo and create a `build.sbt` with the following content:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.5"

projectDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "3.8.1" % "test"

publishTo := {
  val nexus = "https://oss.sonatype.org/"
  if (isSnapshot.value) Some("snapshots" at nexus + "content/repositories/snapshots")
  else Some("releases" at nexus + "service/local/staging/deploy/maven2")
}
```

This is the minimal code that was necessary to get it up and running. sbt seems to require that a publish repo is specified, it also seems to require an explicit Scala version. The dependency is already specified by your linked Maven project.

Of course, you know need to change the URI of `RootProject` to point to the location of your fork.

To your second question: You can reference a commit/tag/branch by appending it to the URI, separated with a `#` sign:

```
uri("git://github.com/your/repo#<commit-hash/tag/branch>")
```